# Greenplum gp_vmem_protect_limit configuration

Tags: greenplum

We are doing a PoC by installing Greenplum on AWS environment. We have setup each of our segment servers as d2.8xlarge instance types which has 240 GB of RAM with no SWAP.

I am now trying to setup the gp_vmem_protect_limit using the formula mentioned in gpdb documents and the value is coming to 25600MB.

But in one of the Zendesk Notes it says that gp_vmem_protect_limit will be breached when "**sessions executing on this segment are attempting together to use more than configured limit**. " Does the **segment** in this text mean Segment Host or number of primary segments?

Also, with the Eager Free option being set I see that the memory utilization is very poor when running the TPC-DS benchmark with 5 concurrent users. I would like to improve the memory utilization of the environment and below are the other memory configurations

```
gpconfig -c gp_vmem_protect_limit -v 25600MB
gpconfig -c max_statement_mem -v 16384MB
gpconfig -c statement_mem -v 2400MB
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jayadeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a calculator for it!
http://greenplum.org/calc/

You should also add a swap file or disk.  It is pretty easy to do in Amazon too.  I would add at least a 4GB swap file to each host when you have 240GB of RAM.

Comment: I used that calculator to come up with the values as mentioned in my original post. Are you suggesting that we setup 4 GB Swap per host or per segment?

Comment: Per host.  It is related to how much RAM you have.

Comment: Thanks @Jon  
Based on 15 concurrent SQL's below values for different memory parameters   
'code'
gpconfig -c gp_vmem_protect_limit -v 25600
gpconfig -c max_statement_mem -v 16384MB
gpconfig -c statement_mem -v 1600MB   

But now I am running into the error 
psql:/pivotalguru/TPC-DS/07_multi_user/5/134.query.95.sql:31: ERROR:  Canceling query because of high VMEM usage. Used: 15058MB, available 2232MB, red zone: 23040MB (runaway_cleaner.c:135)  (seg1 slice285 ip-10-228-2-96:40001 pid=76030) (cdbdisp.c:1326)
<\code>

Comment: I checked the runaway_detector_activation_percent value and it was set to 90 which means that that a SQL cannot use more than 90% of 25GB (vmem_limit) which is 22.5 GB in a segment host server. But the max_statement_mem and the statement_mem parameters will not allow any SQL to use this much of memory and that is where I am having a confusion.

Comment: statement_mem and max_statement_mem are only used when gp_resqueue_memory_policy is set to auto but the default for gp_resqueue_memory_policy is eager_free so your setting is ignored.  eager_free does a good job at releasing memory when possible so I would stick with this setting.  Another way to handle high concurrency is to use a resource queue.  You could, for example, change the ACTIVE_STATEMENTS in the default resource queue from 20 to 10.

Comment: I am running the TPC-DS benchmark from your website :) with 5 concurrent users so I am not sure if running the benchmark with 5 users itself is causing the issue.

Comment: Did you change gp_resqueue_memory_policy to auto?  It doesn't do as good as a job as eager_free to release memory and prevent errors.

Comment: No I did not. I will change it and re-run the test...so for my clarification if we set it to eager_free GPDB will try to allocate as much memory as it can to the SQL in a segment host but will terminate it if reaches the runaway_detector_activation_percent limit in a segment host. Correct?

Comment: Hi Jon, I had turned off the optimizer and I believe that is why the error was showing up. After turning on the optimizer the memory utilization is much better.